# Как добавить уведомления в приложение?

Tags: android, уведомления

Есть приложение, сделанное в Android Studio. Показывает видео с определенных плейлистов Youtube. Соответственно, когда на Youtube загружается новое видео, то оно появляется и в приложении. Нужно дописать код, чтобы приложение показывало уведомление в статус-баре при появлении нового видео. 
Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку или объясните, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl=ru

Comment: "Есть приложение, сделанное в Android Studio" из этих слов, могу сделать предположение, что не вы писали это приложение, так что лучший совет, начните его писать с нуля. А в целом - вам нужно YouTube api. Какой нибудь retrofit - это всё чтобы следить за появлением новых видео на ютюбе, а уведомления - почитайте документацию

Comment: Нет, поняли неправильно. Писал я, писал с нуля, есть исходники программы. Но я новичок и не знаю как делать уведомления. Перед тем как задать вопрос здесь я просмотрел МНОГО разных инструкций, как это делается, но так и не понял.     "А в целом - вам нужно YouTube api."   У меня подключен Youtube API

Comment: ну, тогда прошу прощение) в ответе вам написали куда двигаться, сами нотификейшны это очень просто (документация исчерпывающа). куда сложнее проблема - ловить обновления

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны понять одну принципиальную вещь, что касается уведомлений.

Инициатором уведомлений должен быть бэкенд, т.е. какой-то сервер, который будет сканировать YouTube и в случае новых видео инициировать push notification.

Все решения на стороне клиента, опрос YouTube api с интервалом, сервисы и т.п., это все будет пожирать батарею и интернет пользователя.

Как интегрировать push notifications в приложение, найдете здесь
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю, но зачем сканировать сам Youtube канал, если эти видео появляются автоматически в моем приложении. Значит инициатором уведомлений должно быть мое приложение, а не сервис Firebase. Или я не правильно понимаю?

Comment: Для того чтобы видео появилось в приложении, оно должно быть запущено. Если его запустит пользователь, он и так увидит новое видео, зачем ему еще и уведомление?

Comment: А push notification как раз для того, чтобы уведомить приложение о чем-то даже когда оно не запущено.

Comment: Если вы думаете, что когда видите Facebook, Youtube или Google+ уведомление, то его инициирует приложение на вашем телефоне? Хочу вас разочаровать, это не так.

Answer (score 1):

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
    0, notificationIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Resources res = context.getResources();
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_cat)
        // большая картинка
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.hungrycat))
        //.setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) // текст в строке состояния
        .setTicker("Последнее китайское предупреждение!")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        //.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) // Заголовок уведомления
        .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
        //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
        .setContentText("Пора покормить кота"); // Текст уведомления

// Notification notification = builder.getNotification(); // до API 16
Notification notification = builder.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

здесь более точно описано создание уведомлений
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/notification.php

Comment: ок, сейчас исправлю